# multiple websocket in one html javascript

Tags: javascript, java, d3.js, websocket, apache-kafka

I want create a dynamic trend chart using Websocket as resource.

For example I draw two plot(chart1,chart2) and one connect to ws://localhost:8080/rd1 ,and one to ws://localhost:8080/rd2, which is websocket server building on the tomcat8 and connecting different kafka topic(topic1,topic2) as OnOpen.

For my problem I want to draw two dynamic trend chart connecting 2 different kafka resource. But as I start two chart, all message fill to the later connect chart.
***(i.e. topic1,topic2=> chart2)***

I think is that my javascript code are wrong ,  I'm new to javascript,and don't know how to fix it.

this is my script (selector are id of each chart svg):

```
var WrapperWS =function(selector) {
    var wsUri = "ws://localhost:8080/"+selector;
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
    websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
    websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
    websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
    websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };

    onOpen=function (evt){
        console.log("CONNECTED on ");
     }
    onClose=function (evt){
        console.log("DISCONNECTED");
      }
    onMessage=function (evt){
        drawSomethingonSvg(evt.data);
    }

    onError=function (evt){
        console.log('Error: ' + evt.data);
      }

    this.send = function (message, callback) {
        this.waitForConnection(function () {
            websocket.send(message);
            if (typeof callback !== 'undefined') {
              callback();
            }
        }, 1000);
    };

    this.waitForConnection = function (callback, interval) {
        if (websocket.readyState === 1) {
            callback();
        } else {
            var that = this;
            // optional: implement backoff for interval here
            setTimeout(function () {
                that.waitForConnection(callback, interval);
            }, interval);
        }
    };

}
```

and I will call this function on chart button for each chart

```
function stream_trend_plot_on(selector){var connection = new WrapperWS(selector) }
```

I'm sorry that I'm new to Here can't upload picture yet,
using url instead.https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSpfD.jpg

thank you all

Comment: does `drawSomethingonSvg(evt.data)` take into account the chart which the data belongs to? Because if that's your implementation I don't see a drawing function for each data stream, looks like that function is global?

Comment: Oh and by the way, some functions you defined don't have the `var` keyword in front of them (`onOpen`, `onMessage`,`onClose`). That makes them GLOBAL which means they can be read in any other scope. That might be the issue.

Comment: yes!! add var in front of onOpen those function makes it works , Thanks a lot!!! I should take some course about javascript ,thx!